# Extract the string between nth pattern1 and mth pattern2 - sed/awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

In the example(s) below, how might one return the *string* between the nth pattern1 and mth pattern2, where pattern1 and pattern2 may occur more than once each in the string?

Better Example:

```
zz this is string xx zz another string xx third string zz xx and a tail xx
```

How would you return between the second zz and the third xx?

i.e.

```
another string xx third string zz
```

**Edit:** For anyone looking for this, 'Capture Groups' and 'Forward/Backward Referencing' in regular expressions seems to be the terminology for what is required for this task..[Helpful information here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

### EDITED ABOVE

**Sorry to the inital helpers. Your answers were good, my example was poorly chosen.**

**Feel free to remove from here down to tidy this question up. I'm just leaving it for the sake of completeness for the original answers contributed.**

Poor Original Question and Example:

```
echo '1a 2b 3c 4d 5e 6f 7g 8h 9i 0j'
```

Bonus marks if you can come up with a solution both without trailing spaces. I know leading/trailing spaces could be removed by piping to sed again, but I'm curious if there is a neater solution. The output I would expect (excluding the single quotes) is:

`'3c 4d 5e 6f'` or `' 3c 4d 5e 6f '`

- I'm using sed/awk so that hopefully rather than just matching a single character (space) it **could be expanded to matching the nth occurrence of pattern1 and the mth occurrence of pattern2**, in future.

I tried a few variants. I believe this is the nearest to correct with sed:

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0' | sed -n 's/.*[ ]{2}.*[ ]{4}.*/\1/p'
```

But, it returns the error:

```
sed -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: Will do. I realise now based on two quick and correct answers that the example is insufficient. I'll add something more appropriate.

Comment: A few examples with some edge cases would be helpful. Right now it's difficult to understand what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Hopefully the edited question and example is better. I think 'capture groups' are what I might be chasing, as mentioned in an answer to my poor wording the first time around. Thanks to those that already contributed.

Comment: `echo '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0' | awk '{for (i=3;i<=6;i++) printf (i==3)?"%s":" %s",$i; print""}'` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the plain GNU `sed`:

```
pat1='zz'
n=2
pat2='xx'
m=3

echo 'zz this is string xx zz another string xx third string zz xx and a tail xx' |
sed "s/$pat1/\n/$n; s/$pat2/\n/$m; s/[^\n]*\n//; s/\n.*//"
```

Outputs

```
 another string xx third string zz
```

---

`s/$pat1/\n/$n` replaces the `$n`th `$pat1` with a newline character.
`s/$pat2/\n/$m` replaces the `$m`th `$pat2` with a newline character.
`s/[^\n]*\n//`  deletes the part between the beginning of the string and the first newline character(inclusive).
`s/\n.*//` deletes the part between the newline character(inclusive) and the end of the string.

**Note**: The `sed` command could be simplified slightly as `sed -E "s/$pat1/\n/$n; s/$pat2/\n/$m; s/.*\n(.*)\n.*/\1/"`

Comment: Clever implementation. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`

```
$ s='zz this is string xx zz another string xx third string zz xx and a tail xx'

$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/((.*?xx){3}).*/$1/'
zz this is string xx zz another string xx third string zz xx

$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/((.*?xx){3}).*/$1=~s#(.*?zz){2}\s*|\s*xx$##gr/e'
another string xx third string zz
```

The first command `s/((.*?xx){3}).*/$1/` shows how to get up to third occurrence of `xx` where `.*?` is non-greedy matching to consume as minimally as possible.

The `e` flag allows Perl code in replacement section, so you can modify this string to remove up to second occurrence of `zz` and the last `xx` with `$1=~s#(.*?zz){2}\s*|\s*xx$##gr`

Comment: Thanks Sundeep, this looks like it does the job. Perl is new to me, so I'll take some time to digest it, but I appreciate this answer.

Comment: @Chris sure, see my [perl one-liners chapter](https://github.com/learnbyexample/Command-line-text-processing/blob/master/perl_the_swiss_knife.md) for examples and explanations

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    n = 2
    m = 3
}
{
    $0 = encode($0)
    beg = match($0,"([^<]*<){"n"}") + RLENGTH
    end = match($0,"([^>]*>){"m-1"}[^>]+") + RLENGTH
    print decode(substr($0,beg,end-beg))
}

function encode(str) {
    gsub(/@/,"@A",str); gsub(/</,"@B",str); gsub(/>/,"@C",str)
    gsub(/zz/,"<",str); gsub(/xx/,">",str)
    return str
}

function decode(str) {
    gsub(/>/,"xx",str); gsub(/</,"zz",str)
    gsub(/@C/,">",str); gsub(/@B/,"<",str); gsub(/@A/,"@",str)
    return str
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
 another string xx third string zz
```

The `encode()` and `decode()` functions are how to turn the strings you're interested in into single chars that cannot exist anywhere in the input so you can then negate them in a bracket expression as used in the `match()` calls.

Comment: Thanks for this. I decided to accept the sed solution as the answer, simply because it's less verbose, but this might have a portability advantage,so definitely I'll be hanging on to this one!